# Postgres finding transitions

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to find all periods of time a system is in a specific state. The state is logged into a table. An example of the data is as follows:

```
Time - State  
12:00 - 1  
12:01 - 1  
12:02 - 1  
12:03 - 1  
12:04 - 0  
12:05 - 0  
12:06 - 0  
12:07 - 1  
12:08 - 1
```

The result I would like to see is:

```
Start - End - State  
12:00 - 12:03 - 1  
12:04 - 12:06 - 0  
12:07 - 12:08 - 1
```

Is there any predefined function to find the transition records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT "State",
       MIN("Time") AS Start,
       MAX("Time") AS End     
FROM (
  SELECT "Time", "State",
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "Time") - 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "State" ORDER BY "Time") AS grp
  FROM mytable) AS t
GROUP BY "State", grp
```

The inner query uses a standard technique in order to identify *islands* of consecutive records having the same `State` value. The outer query uses computed column `grp` to `GROUP BY` and get `Start`, `End` values of each *island*.

Comment: This is doing exactly what I hoped. Great!